# Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser - JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing

I am trying to run a LoadTest on Apache JMeter 5.2, when i try to run the test, it shows me this error =>

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.BaseParser.getParser(BaseParser.java:66) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.getParser(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1481) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.downloadPageResources(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1332) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1749) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:556) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:648) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.downloadPageResources(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1417) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1749) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:556) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:648) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1282) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1271) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

What could be the reason?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your JMeter installation got corrupt somehow, try uninstalling `jmeter - HTTP Protocol Support` component using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/) and then reinstall it back

[image]

it should fix your installation issue.

---

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so given your current JMeter installation is broken it's probably a good time to upgrade to [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: I´ve updated Jmeter to the latest version and i´ve made the things that you said regarding the plugin and the same error appears :(

Answer (score 0):

I´ve fixed it by reconfiguring the HTTP Request on each test.